# Flutter button with a png with transparency

Tags: button, dart, flutter

it would be simple but i can't make it work like i would like to. I would like to have a custom made png and make it act like a RaisedButton where I can edit the splashColor, highlightColor, adding a border ( widht and colors of it) and have the ripple effect of Ink but only on the visible part of the png. Trying this at the moment:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Buttons practice"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
        //Button1
        new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            child: new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: new Image.asset(
                "assets/Freccia.png",
              ),
            ))
        ],
      ),

      //Button2
      new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height:150 ,
            width: 150,
            child: new FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: new Image.asset(
              "assets/Freccia.png",)),
          )],
          ),

          //Button3
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                child: new OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: new Image.asset(
                        "assets/Freccia.png")
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I click the center one for example the ripple effect is applied to the whole container of 150x 150

Comment: isn't there a way to import path from a svg?

Answer (score 0):

So far, what I've been thinking to implement what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("Flutter Sample - Irregular shaped RaisedButton"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          shape: _CustomBorder(),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  const _CustomBorder();

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return const EdgeInsets.only();
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.left + rect.width / 2.0, rect.top)
      ..lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 3, rect.top + rect.height / 3)
      ..lineTo(rect.right, rect.top + rect.height / 2.0)
      ..lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 3, rect.top + 2 * rect.height / 3)
      ..lineTo(rect.left + rect.width / 2.0, rect.bottom)
      ..lineTo(rect.left + rect.width / 3, rect.top + 2 * rect.height / 3)
      ..lineTo(rect.left, rect.top + rect.height / 2.0)
      ..lineTo(rect.left + rect.width / 3, rect.top + rect.height / 3)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  // This border doesn't support scaling.
  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`RaisedButton` accepts shape property. I built a custom `ShapeBorder` and assigned this object to the shape property of `RaisedButton`.

I've created a new class `_CustomBorder` that extends `ShapeBorder`. In this class, I've overridden some of the methods of `ShapeBorder`.

The method that needs focus is `getOuterPath()`. In this method, I return a `Path` object. If you observe, I've used moveTo(), lineTo() and close() methods to build the custom shape. You check [Paths in Flutter: A Visual Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) to dig more on this.

If you have decided of what shape you are going to draw, you can just replace this part of the code:

```
body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          shape: _CustomBorder(),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

If you'll run my code above, this is what would you get:

[image]

Also, when you've read the blog, [ClipPath, Custom Painter, and Flutter CustomClipper made it fast!](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clippath-custom-painter-and-flutter-customclipper-made-it-fast-a2d0b7d10e9d), it was mentioned that there are existing tools that converts `.svg` files to `Path`.